# cluster algorithm in ruby skips array index

Tags: ruby

I wrote a cluster algorithm in ruby, but I cannot figure out why the size of the elements before the clustering is 67 and the size of the elements after the clustering is 66. Somewhere an index is skipped from array.

```
MarkerCluster.new(reports, distance, zoom).clusterize

class MarkerCluster

  ...        
  def initialize(markers, distance, zoom)
    @markers, @distance, @zoom = markers, distance, zoom
    @map_markers = []
  end

  ...
  def clusterize 
    puts "The size of markers before clustering #{@markers.size}" # prints 67
    marker_count = 0
    cluster.each do |item|
      if item.is_a?(Array)
        marker_count += item.size
        map_markers << create_map_marker(item)
      else
        marker_count += 1
        map_markers << item
      end
    end
    puts "The size of markers after clustering: #{marker_count}" # prints 66
    to_map 
  end
...
# return collection where coordinates closer than distance are clustered together.
  def cluster
    cluster_list = []

   i = j = 0
   i = markers.size - 1
   while(i > 0)
     cluster = []     
     j = i - 1

     while(j > 0)
       pixels = pixel_distance(markers[i].latitude, markers[i].longitude, 
                                markers[j].latitude, markers[j].longitude)
       if distance > pixels
         cluster << markers[j]
         j -= 1
       else                  
         break
       end          
     end

     if cluster.size > 0
       cluster << markers[i]
       cluster_list << cluster
       i = j + 1
     else
       # no cluster, so just add single marker
       cluster_list << markers[i]
     end
     i -= 1
   end

   cluster_list
  end
```

As you can see, I just iterate through an array and compare indexes to determine if they belong in a cluster or as a single unit. But I cannot figure out where the cluster method skips an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this line should be `while (i >=0)` instead. Because while initializing the value of `i = markers.size -1` and again when its checked for i > 0 then index i=0 is not considered.

Let me know if it helps